# Show notification on foreground react native firebase v6

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am using the latest react native version 0.62 and latest version of react-native-firebase i.e. v6. I am able to get the notification and it working fine on the background but its not displaying on foreground.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
checkPermission = async () => {
    const enabled = await messaging().hasPermission();
    console.log('enabled ******* ',enabled)
    if (enabled) {
      this.getFcmToken();
    } else {
      this.requestPermission();
    }
  };

  getFcmToken = async () => {
    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
      console.log('Your Firebase Token is:', fcmToken);
      // this.showAlert('Your Firebase Token is:', fcmToken);
    } else {
      console.log('Failed', 'No token received');
    }
  };

  requestPermission = async () => {
    try {
      await messaging().requestPermission();
      // User has authorised
    } catch (error) {
      // User has rejected permissions
    }
  };

  messageListener = async () => {
    console.log('inside message listener ****** ')

    messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
  };

  showAlert = (title, message) => {
    Alert.alert(
      title,
      message,
      [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') }],
      { cancelable: false },
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkPermission();
    this.messageListener();
  }
```

Comment: hello  brother did u find solution for this

Comment: @ikmo if you are still in the issue, I have added answer please check.

Answer (score 28):

By default **rnfirebase** not supporting displaying notification popup when app is in foreground state as they mentioned [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#notifications). So push notification pop up only displayed when app is in background state or closed.

So if you want to display push notification on foreground mode also then you have to use extra library which will be display fired push notification as local notification as mention in their documentation.

> If the RemoteMessage payload contains a notification property when sent to the onMessage handler, the device will not show any notification to the user. Instead, you could trigger a local notification or update the in-app UI to signal a new notification.

So as a solution you can use [react-native-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) to fire push notification when app in foreground.

To do so, just install it by command :

> npm i react-native-push-notification

For android you don't need to follow any native installation steps just install library by this command and then you can fire local push notification as below :
Create a file called **NotificationController.android.js** :

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

const NotificationController = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      PushNotification.localNotification({
        message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
        bigPictureUrl: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
        smallIcon: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
      });
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default NotificationController;
```

Now, when app is in foreground state and if `onMessage` receive any message from firebase then `PushNotification` will fire local notification.

**Update: For iOS**
For iOS you have to install `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios` using this command:

> npm i @react-native-community/push-notification-ios

Also follow all the native installation steps as suggested in document.

Then you can create file called **NotificationController.ios.js** where you can handle notification for iOS.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIos from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';

const NotificationController = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  // Called when application is open by clicking on notification
  // and called when application is already opend and user click on notification

  PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification: (notification) => {
      if (notification) {
        console.log(notification);
        Alert.alert('Opened push notification', JSON.stringify(notification));
      }
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Usesd to display notification when app is in foreground
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      PushNotificationIos.addNotificationRequest({
        id: remoteMessage.messageId,
        body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
        userInfo: remoteMessage.data,
      });
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default NotificationController;
```

Now, call `<NotificationController />` in you Home screen or App initial routing file.

Comment: `react-native-push-notificatio` not working untile the channel is getting create how did you achieved the same? Thanks

Comment: I don't think a channel needs to be created to push notifications to get works.

Comment: it need a channelId to work ? any one with the solution my issue is I how can I handle click on notification when app is open, it works in background or in quit state.

Comment: @SamiUllah if you click on the notification, it would open the app if it's in the background not sure if it is killed/quit state.

Comment: yes, using FCM i have made things work but when app is running, FCM doesn't support notifications in that case, but react-push-notifications work but dere seems to way to navigate to a particular page on notification click, although we can write navigation.navigate in onNotification but it will fire also when notification arrives.

Comment: use react-native-push-notification for local notifications.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the above solutions...
I just wanted to add that, if you don't have channel id the use

```
PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel', // (required)
      channelName: 'My channel', // (required)
      channelDescription: 'A channel to categorise your notifications', // (optional) default: undefined.
      soundName: 'default', // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
      importance: 4, // (optional) default: 4. Int value of the Android notification importance
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
    },
    created => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`),
  );
```

and be careful while using

```
const dat = {
      channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel', // (required)
      channelName: 'My channel',
      //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
      message: notification.body, // (required)
      title: notification.title,
    };
console.log(dat)
PushNotification.localNotification(dat);
```

In some case when  title: undefined, or title: Object{}, same for message might be happening so console log every thing and put it inside localNotification fuction

Answer (score 0):

Following @Kishan Bharda solution, I had to do something different for IOS foreground notifications (here, I have the code in index.js instead of a different file):

```
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    // Must be outside of any component LifeCycle (such as `componentDidMount`).
    PushNotification.configure({
        onNotification: function (notification) {
            console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
            const { foreground, userInteraction, title, message } = notification;
            if (foreground && (title || message) && !userInteraction) PushNotification.localNotification(notification);
            notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
        }
    });
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```