# React-native firebase push notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

//this is my notificationservice.tsx file

```
`import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
 import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
 import axios from 'axios';

// Function to request user permission for notifications
export async function requestUserPermission() {
  try {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
      await getFcmToken();
    } else {
      console.log('Notification permission denied.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error requesting permission:', error);
  }
}

// Function to get the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) token
const getFcmToken = async () => {
  try {
    let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
    console.log('Stored FCM Token:', fcmToken);

    if (!fcmToken) {
      const newFcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
      if (newFcmToken) {
        console.log('New FCM Token generated:', newFcmToken);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', newFcmToken);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting or setting FCM Token:', error);
  }
}

// Function to listen for incoming notifications
export const notificationListener = async () => {
  // Listener for when the app is in the background and the user opens the notification
  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
    console.log('Notification opened from background state:', remoteMessage.notification);
  });

  // Listener for receiving notifications while the app is in the foreground
  messaging().onMessage(remoteMessage => {
    console.log('Received notification in foreground state:', remoteMessage);
  });

  // Check if the app was opened from a notification (when it was previously quit)
  messaging()
    .getInitialNotification()
    .then(remoteMessage => {
      if (remoteMessage) {
        console.log('Notification caused app to open from quit state:', remoteMessage.notification);
      } else {
        console.log('No initial notification found.');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error getting initial notification:', error);
    });
}
```

with this code i found issue that when my phone is locked or when my application is closed when i send notification with FCM tester the notification shown in my screen but when i try to send notification ,when my application is active i cant able to show notification on top of the my screen.

I also add all dependencies in build.gradle file and Androidmanifest.xml file
[and this is my index.js file for set background notification. this background notification is also work ]  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvmXl.png)
[look this image in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRi0d.png)  only onmessage working . with getinitial notification i found No initial notification found, null this i want that all this message state is work.

Comment: iOS can you always set PRIORITY to HIGH when sending notifications? Occasionally, iOS ignore notification with low priority.

Comment: take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437271/show-notification-on-foreground-react-native-firebase-v6